# Python trying to run one Async function and one infinite loop simultaneously

Tags: python, async-await, salesforce

I am trying to monitor a stream of salesforce events to play a ringtone each time a case comes in based on case origin. Initially I was querying the API from a thread and I was able to have the UI run in the main function and the monitoring run on a thread in the background. Now that I have switched to the streaming API I need to use async to monitor for responses when a case is assigned. This has caused issues where if I start the async loop first my UI never starts but if I start the UI first my async loop never starts.... I have attached my code below:

Here is my first python script where I actually define the async function and call my user interface.

```
import asyncio
from aiosfstream import SalesforceStreamingClient
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
import  Ringtone
from threading import Thread
import vlc



def notifier(type, system):
    n = ToastNotifier()
    n.show_toast("SalesForce Notification Manager", "Incoming " + type + " From" + system, duration=10,
                 icon_path="ICON.ico")

async def subscribeToSalesforce():
    async with SalesforceStreamingClient(
            # Connect to Salesforce streaming API
            consumer_key='<key>',
            consumer_secret='<secret>',
            username='<username>',
            password='<password>',
            sandbox=True) as client:
        # Subscribe to one or more topics
        apiLink = Ringtone.login()
        currentUserID = Ringtone.getUserID(apiLink)
        await client.subscribe("/event/NewEmail__e")

        # listen for incoming messages
        async for message in client:
            topic = message["channel"]
            data = message["data"]
            print(f"{topic}: {data}")
            data = data['payload']
            try:
                print(data['Assigned__c'])
                if data['Assigned__c']:
                    if data['Assigned__c'] == 'Assigned':
                        if data['OwnerID__c'] == currentUserID:
                            print(data)
                            findType(data)
            except:
                print('Exception')

def findType(data):
    with open('Ref/Files/phone.txt') as f:
        phone = f.readline()
        f.close()
    with open('Ref/Files/email.txt') as f:
        email = f.readline()
        f.close()
    with open('Ref/Files/chat.txt') as f:
        chat = f.readline()
        f.close()
    with open('Ref/Files/Volume.txt') as f:
        volume = f.readline()
        f.close()
    with open('Ref/Files/notifs.txt') as f:
        notifsRaw = f.readline()
        f.close()
    notifs = True
    if data['Assigned__c']:
        if data['Assigned__c'] == 'Assigned':
            if data['VM_Offline_Chat__c'] == True:
                if notifs:
                    t2 = Thread(target=notifier, args=("Voicemail/Offline Chat", data['Program__c']))
                    t2.start()
                p = vlc.MediaPlayer()
                p.audio_set_volume(int(volume))
                p.play()
            elif data['Case_Type__c'] == 'Phone':
                if notifs:
                    t3 = Thread(target=notifier, args=("Call", data['Program__c']))
                    t3.start()
                p = vlc.MediaPlayer(phone)
                p.audio_set_volume(int(volume))
                p.play()
            elif data['Case_Type__c'] == 'Email':
                if notifs:
                    t4 = Thread(target=notifier, args=("Email", data['Program__c']))
                    t4.start()
                p = vlc.MediaPlayer(email)
                p.audio_set_volume(int(volume))
                p.play()
            elif data['Case_Type__c'] == 'Chat':
                if notifs:
                    t5 = Thread(target=notifier, args=("Chat", data['Program__c']))
                    t5.start()
                p = vlc.MediaPlayer(chat)
                p.audio_set_volume(int(volume))
                p.play()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(subscribeToSalesforce())
    t1 = Thread(target=Ringtone.userInterface(), args=[])
    t1.start()
```

Here is my other python file where the user interface function is stored:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time
import vlc
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import distutils.util


_VARS = {'window': False,
         'fig_agg': False,
         'pltFig': False}

ttk_style = 'Clam'
sg.theme('DarkGrey5')

with open('Ref/Files/Volume.txt') as f:
    sliderVal = f.readline()
    f.close()
with open('Ref/Files/chatchosen.txt') as f:
    chatchosen = f.readline()
    f.close()
with open('Ref/Files/emailchosen.txt') as f:
    emailchosen = f.readline()
    f.close()
with open('Ref/Files/phonechosen.txt') as f:
    phonechosen = f.readline()
    f.close()
with open('Ref/Files/notifs.txt') as f:
    notifs = f.readline()
    f.close()

notifs = bool(distutils.util.strtobool(notifs))

command = ['Test Ringtone']
cmd_layout = [[sg.Button(cmd, use_ttk_buttons=True, size=(10, 1))] for cmd in command]

ringtones = ['Classical Piano', 'Mozart', 'Game of Thrones', 'Harry Potter', 'Mandalorian', 'Star Wars', 'Play That Funky Music', 'You Are My Sunshine', 'iPhone', 'Blackberry', 'Minimal 1', 'Minimal 2', 'Minimal 3']

def open_window(name):
    Title = 'Enter Salesforce Username:'
    Window = 'Username'
    LayoutItems = [
        [sg.Text(Title)],
        [sg.Input(name, key='edit')],
        [sg.Button('Okay', use_ttk_buttons=True), sg.Button('Cancel', use_ttk_buttons=True)]
    ]

    window = sg.Window(Window, LayoutItems, resizable=True, modal=True)
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
        elif event == "Cancel":
            window.close()
            return 'Cancel'
        elif event == "Okay":
            if values['edit'] != '':
                window.close()
                return values['edit']
            else:
                window.close()
                return values['edit']

def open_password(name, num):
    if num == 4:
        Title = 'Enter Salesforce Password:'
        Window = 'Password'
    elif num == 5:
        Title = 'Enter Salesforce Security Token:'
        Window = 'Token'
    LayoutItems = [
        [sg.Text(Title)],
        [sg.Input(name, key='edit', password_char='*')],
        [sg.Button('Okay', use_ttk_buttons=True), sg.Button('Cancel', use_ttk_buttons=True)]
    ]

    window = sg.Window(Window, LayoutItems, resizable=True, modal=True)
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
        elif event == "Cancel":
            window.close()
            return 'Cancel'
        elif event == "Okay":
            if values['edit'] != '':
                window.close()
                return values['edit']
            else:
                window.close()
                return values['edit']

def login():
    with open('Ref/Files/Info1.txt') as f:
        usernameold = f.readline()
    with open('Ref/Files/Info2.txt') as f:
        passwordold = f.readline()
    with open('Ref/Files/Info3.txt') as f:
        tokenold = f.readline()

    username = open_window(usernameold)
    password = open_password(passwordold, 4)
    token = open_password(tokenold, 5)

    with open('Ref/Files/Info1.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(username)
    with open('Ref/Files/Info2.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(password)
    with open('Ref/Files/Info3.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(token)

    try:
        sf = Salesforce(username=username, password=password, security_token=token, domain='test')
    except:
        sg.popup('Incorrect Username/Password Combination')
    return sf

def getUserID(apiLink):
    identity_url = API.restful('')['identity']
    currentUser = API.User.get(identity_url[-18:])
    currentUserID = currentUser['Id']
    return currentUserID


employee_list_column = [
    [sg.Image('K2.png', size=(280, 100))],
    [sg.Listbox(values=ringtones, enable_events=True, size=(40, 20), key="RingtoneList"), sg.Column(cmd_layout)],
    [sg.Checkbox('Enable Windows Notifications', default=notifs, key="notifsBox")],
    [sg.Button('Save Phone Ringtone Selection', use_ttk_buttons=True, key='PhoneRingtone'), sg.Text(phonechosen, key= 'PhoneChosen')],
    [sg.Button('Save Email Ringtone Selection', use_ttk_buttons=True, key='EmailRingtone'), sg.Text(emailchosen, key= 'EmailChosen')],
    [sg.Button('Save Chat Ringtone Selection', use_ttk_buttons=True, key='ChatRingtone'), sg.Text(chatchosen, key= 'ChatChosen')],
    [sg.Slider(orientation ='horizontal', key='Volume', range=(20,100), default_value= int(sliderVal), enable_events=True)]
]

layout = [
    [
        sg.Column(employee_list_column)
    ]
]


def chooseRingtones(chosen):
    if chosen == 'Classical Piano':
        val = '/Ref/Audio/ClassicalPiano.mp3'
    elif chosen == 'Mozart':
        val = '/Ref/Audio/Mozart.mp3'
    elif chosen == 'Mandalorian':
        val = '/Ref/Audio/mandalorian_call.mp3'
    elif chosen == 'Game of Thrones':
        val = '/Ref/Audio/GOT.mp3'
    elif chosen == 'Harry Potter':
        val = '/Ref/Audio/HarryPotter.mp3'
    elif chosen == 'Star Wars':
        val = '/Ref/Audio/Imperial.mp3'
    elif chosen == 'Play That Funky Music':
        val = '/Ref/Audio/PlayThatFunky.mp3'
    elif chosen == 'You Are My Sunshine':
        val = '/Ref/Audio/YouAreMySunshine.mp3'
    elif chosen == 'ival':
        val = '/Ref/Audio/ival.mp3'
    elif chosen == 'Minimal 1':
        val = '/Ref/Audio/Normal1.mp3'
    elif chosen == 'Minimal 2':
        val = '/Ref/Audio/Normal2.mp3'
    elif chosen == 'Minimal 3':
        val = '/Ref/Audio/Normal3.mp3'
    return val

def userInterface():
    start_time = time.time() - 5
    window = sg.Window("Salesforce Notification Manager", layout, resizable=True)
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        with open('Ref/Files/Volume.txt') as f:
            volume = f.readline()
            f.close()
        if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            programClose = True
            break
        elif event == 'Test Ringtone':
            name = values['RingtoneList']
            if name:
                if start_time + 1 <= time.time():
                    start_time = time.time()
                    chosen = name[0]
                    if chosen == 'Classical Piano':
                        p = vlc.MediaPlayer("/Ref/Audio/ClassicalPiano.mp3")
                        p.audio_set_volume(int(volume))
                        p.play()
                    elif chosen == 'Mozart':
                        p = vlc.MediaPlayer("/Ref/Audio/Mozart.mp3")
                        p.audio_set_volume(int(volume))
                        p.play()
                    elif chosen == 'Mandalorian':
                        p = vlc.MediaPlayer('/Ref/Audio/mandalorian_call.mp3')
                        p.audio_set_volume(int(volume))
                        p.play()
                    elif chosen == 'Game of Thrones':
                        p = vlc.MediaPlayer('/Ref/Audio/GOT.mp3')
                        p.audio_set_volume(int(volume))
                        p.play()
                    elif chosen == 'Harry Potter':
                        p = vlc.MediaPlayer('/Ref/Audio/HarryPotter.mp3')
                        p.audio_set_volume(int(volume))
                        p.play()
                    elif chosen == 'Star Wars':
                        p = vlc.MediaPlayer('/Ref/Audio/Imperial.mp3')
                        p.audio_set_volume(int(volume))
                        p.play()
                    elif chosen == 'Play That Funky Music':
                        p = vlc.MediaPlayer('/Ref/Audio/PlayThatFunky.mp3')
                        p.audio_set_volume(int(volume))
                        p.play()
                    elif chosen == 'You Are My Sunshine':
                        p = vlc.MediaPlayer('/Ref/Audio/YouAreMySunshine.mp3')
                        p.audio_set_volume(int(volume))
                        p.play()
                    elif chosen == 'iPhone':
                        p = vlc.MediaPlayer('/Ref/Audio/iPhone.mp3')
                        p.audio_set_volume(int(volume))
                        p.play()
                    elif chosen == 'Blackberry':
                        p = vlc.MediaPlayer('/Ref/Audio/Blackberry.mp3')
                        p.audio_set_volume(int(volume))
                        p.play()
                    elif chosen == 'Minimal 1':
                        p = vlc.MediaPlayer('/Ref/Audio/Normal1.mp3')
                        p.audio_set_volume(int(volume))
                        p.play()
                    elif chosen == 'Minimal 2':
                        p = vlc.MediaPlayer('/Ref/Audio/Normal2.m4a')
                        p.audio_set_volume(int(volume))
                        p.play()
                    elif chosen == 'Minimal 3':
                        p = vlc.MediaPlayer('/Ref/Audio/Normal3.mp3')
                        p.audio_set_volume(int(volume))
                        p.play()
            else:
                sg.Popup('No Ringtone Selected')
        elif event == 'PhoneRingtone':
            name = values['RingtoneList']
            if name:
                chosen = name[0]
                chosen1 = "Phone Ringtone Chosen:   " + chosen
                window['PhoneChosen'].update(value=chosen1)
                phone = chooseRingtones(chosen)
                with open('Ref/Files/phonechosen.txt', 'w') as f:
                    f.write(str(chosen1))
                    f.close()
                with open('Ref/Files/phone.txt', 'w') as f:
                    f.write(phone)
                    f.close()
            else:
                sg.Popup('No Ringtone Selected')
        elif event == 'ChatRingtone':
            name = values['RingtoneList']
            if name:
                chosen = name[0]
                chosen1 = " Chat Ringtone Chosen:   " + chosen
                window['ChatChosen'].update(value=chosen1)
                chat = chooseRingtones(chosen)
                with open('Ref/Files/emailchosen.txt', 'w') as f:
                    f.write(str(chosen1))
                    f.close()
                with open('Ref/Files/chat.txt', 'w') as f:
                    f.write(chat)
                    f.close()
            else:
                sg.Popup('No Ringtone Selected')
        elif event == 'EmailRingtone':
            name = values['RingtoneList']
            if name:
                chosen = name[0]
                chosen1 = "Email Ringtone Chosen:   " + chosen
                window['EmailChosen'].update(value=chosen1)
                email = chooseRingtones(chosen)
                with open('Ref/Files/chatchosen.txt', 'w') as f:
                    f.write(str(chosen1))
                    f.close()
                with open('Ref/Files/email.txt', 'w') as f:
                    f.write(email)
                    f.close()
            else:
                sg.popup('No ringtone is selected')
        elif event == 'Volume':
            slider = window[event]
            volume = int(slider.TKScale.get())
            with open('Ref/Files/Volume.txt', 'w') as f:
                f.write(str(volume))
                f.close()
        elif event == 'notifsBox':
            notifs = values["notifsBox"]
            with open('Ref/Files/notifs.txt', 'w') as f:
                f.write(str(notifs))
                f.close()
```

Sorry if my code is sloppy. I'm new to all of this and the async stuff specifically is very confusing for me.

Comment: Remove anything not necessary to build one simplest script to test Async function to work with your GUI, and anybody can run it, so people know how to help.